# Find multiple cells of data in column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to know if my 7 cells of data on right column had any exact match in left column and tell me where is the location of matched data as a result.
Like it has to be the same order.

[image: Example]

I've tried using `INDEX` and `AGGREGATE` function but got confused since it's a multiple data in same order that I have to find in rows of data.

Is there any right command/function to do this?

Comment: My original answer would only work for single character entries. I have corrected my answer so it will work for longer numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `TEXTJOIN` function, try:

***Edit***
*As pointed out by @AdamV, my first solution would only work on single character entries in the diff column.  I have modified it to work on your data as shown*

*Original incorrect solution
`=FIND(TEXTJOIN(,,what_to_find),TEXTJOIN(,,diff%))`*

***Corrected formula:***
*we pad each entry so that all have the same number of characters before doing the find*

```
=INT(FIND(TEXTJOIN(,,RIGHT(REPT("0",16)&what_to_find,16)),TEXTJOIN(,,RIGHT(REPT("0",16)&diff,16)))/16)+1
```

It will return the position in the left hand column where the right hand column pattern starts.

Comment: whoa! thanks, it's just really a simple tweak

Comment: Won't that give the character position, rather than the row? And since the text in each cell is of variable length, this might not be the most helpful. Helper columns to "pad" the numbers to fixed length using something like =TEXT(cell_to_left,"+0.000000;-0.000000;0.000000;@") might do the trick, then TEXTJOIN those helper columns against each other

Comment: @AdamV Duh, you are absolutely correct.  I was testing with only single character ranges.  I will make the change and credit you.  But if you want to post the answer separately, I will delete mine.